# Problems with library compiled from source code for SDK versions Greater than ios5

Tags: objective-c, ios6

I am doing iphone project, in that am using ODataProtocol, but i can't able to find the Odatagen library for iOS 6, in OData Upto iOS 4.3 libraries.. how can i use that Odata in my app for iOS 6.

Comment: What is `ODataProtocol`, `Odatagen` and `OData`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% positive what the O.P. is looking for, but I'm guessing it's [Microsoft's Open Data Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Data_Protocol).  I found an ["ODataForObjC" project on github](http://odata.github.io/OData4ObjC/).

This SDK hasn't been updated in almost a year, but I just built the "crimeData" sample app that comes from that project in Xcode 5 with no hassles except tons of "deprecated" warnings and the actual service it's trying to connect to is throwing a "403" error.